# gcc make install error

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch, make-install

I try to compile gcc with make install and it gives me this:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/BOSS/sources/gcc-build'
/bin/bash ../gcc-4.8.1/mkinstalldirs /tools /tools
/bin/bash: line 3: cd: ./fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/BOSS/sources/gcc-build'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I am currently compiling it for [lfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html) also I am in a seprate directory on a 32 bit computer

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is caused by the target install. So my advice is to check the line in MakeFile which relates to [install].

Perhaps you may want to share more details for better solutions.